# Rails, activerecord: self[:attribute] vs self.attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When accessing active record column/attributes in rails, what is the difference between using self[:attribute] vs self.attribute? Does this affect getters and setters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're both just methods to get to the attribute - they're both just getters. `self.attribtue` is a more "traditional" getter, whereas `self[:attribute]` is basically just the `[]` method. Switching between using either has no ramifications.

I'd recommend using only the `self.attribute` method because it's syntactically nicer. However, using the `self[:attribute]` can come in handy when something else overrides the `self.attribute` method.

For example, suppose you have a User model with a `name` database column, so you'd get `user.name`. But let's say you install a gem that adds a `#name` method to each of your models. To avoid the complication, one option is to use `user[:name]` to access it directly without going through the compromised method.

Comment: This just bit me yesterday. The answer of Frank Koehl is right.

Answer (score 11):

There's a key difference that the accepted answer misses. If you are attempting to **modify the attribute while setting the value**, then you *must* use  `self[:attribute]`.

For example...

```
def some_attr=(val)
  self.some_attr = val.downcase   # winds up calling itself
end
```

This won't work, because it's self-referencing (you'll get a "Stack too deep"
 error). Instead you must assign the value by doing...

```
def some_attr=(val)
  self[:some_attr] = val.downcase
end
```

There's also a named method [`write_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute), which performs the same action as `self[:attribute]`. Both do what you need, it's a matter of coding style and personal preference. I like `write_attribute` when the attribute I'm actually defining is variable, e.g.

```
write_attribute(var, 'some value')
```